# Is there any fight between Vṛshava Avatara of Śiva and Viṣṇu?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas

I saw this in Devon ke Dev Mahadev  and Vighnaharta Ganesha serial.But does this have any scriptural reference? Did Śiva killed viṣṇu here and his sons ? Did Śiva really gave another Sudarshana chakra to viṣṇu here after the battle ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this story is mentioned in [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226418.html) and [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226419.html) chapter of Shiva Purana.

Summary.:

While chasing Asuras to Patala after Samudra Manthan, Stuck by the arrows of Kama, Lord Vishnu started staying with the maidens came out during Sanudra manthan in Patala. His sons started creating havoc. Thus, on the request of Lord Brahma and the devas. Bhagawan Shiva went there in the form of Vrishabha (Bull) and killed all his sons and after fighting Lord Vishnu he made Lord Vishnu come to his senses. And he also gave him another Sudarshan Chakra much better than the previous one and told him to leave the old one in Patala for the good of Patala. And also cursed every devas saying if anyone except asuras comes there for sexual pleasure, etc they will burn to ashes.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Are these serials **sequentially** based on puranas or pick own stories from puranas and compile them into own episode?

Comment: Mostly they do but sometimes they don't.